# javac: invalid flag: ./src/median_degree.java in ubuntu

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu

Getting errors in Ubuntu while running command ./run1.sh

```
javac: invalid flag: ./src/edge.java
```

In run1.sh file

```
javac -cp .:libs/java-json.jar ./src/median_degree.java ./src/edge.java
java -cp .:libs/java-json.jar:./src median_degree
```

file structure-

[image]

Please help me on how to write script file for this.

Comment: Odd. Are you able to compile this on command line using the same `javac` command?

Comment: It was working on command line. I have created new script file and all commands are working fine.